# programming R loop

Tags: r, for-loop, rank

I need help with programming R. I have data.frame B with one column

```
x<- c("300","300","300","400","400","400","500","500","500"....etc.)  **2 milion rows**
```

and I need create next columns with rank. Next columns should look as

```
y<- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,......etc. )
```

I used cycle with for

```
B$y[1]=1
for (i in 2:length(B$x))
{  
     B$y[i]<-ifelse(B$x[i]==B$x[i-1], B$y[i-1]+1, 1)
}
```

The process ran for 4 hours.

So I need help anything speed up or anything else.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Will the values in `x` always repeat three times?

Comment: can the values in x repeat later in the sequence? E.g. can we have "300" again after "500"

Comment: The values will not always repeat . The next values can be ,800,800,800 .  And it may not be values.
it can be a column c<-("Pv1","Pv1","Pv1","Pv2","Pv2,"Pv2","Pv4","Pv4","Pv4"....etc.) or column c<-("Pv1","Pv1","Pv2","Pv2","Pv3,"Pv3","Pv4","Pv4",....etc.)

Comment: can you clarify. "will not always repeat" is not the same as "will never repeat".

Comment: will never repeat

Comment: using `library(data.table)`, you can do `B[, y := 1:.N, by=x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
B <- data.frame(x = rep(c(300, 400, 400), sample(c(5:10), 3)))
B
B$y <- ave(B$x, B$x, FUN=seq_along)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` that takes about 0.2 seconds on 2 million rows.

First I make sample data:

```
n = 2E6  # number of rows in test
library(dplyr)
sample_data <- data.frame(
  x = round(runif(n = n, min = 1, max = 100000), digits = 0)
) %>%
  arrange(x)  # Optional, added to make output clearer so that each x is adjacent to the others that match.
```

Then I group by x and make `y` show which # occurrence of `x` it is within that group.

```
sample_data_with_rank <- sample_data %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(y = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

head(sample_data_with_rank, 20)

# A tibble: 20 x 2
       x     y
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     1     2
 3     1     3
 4     1     4
 5     1     5
 6     1     6
 7     1     7
 8     1     8
 9     1     9
10     1    10
11     1    11
12     1    12
13     1    13
14     1    14
15     1    15
16     2     1
17     2     2
18     2     3
19     2     4
20     2     5
```

Comment: i have only basic package and i think that dplyr are in other package .That´s right?

Comment: Yes, `dplyr` is the most popular package for R. To add it, you would type `install.packages("dplyr")`. I highly recommend it for this sort of operation.

Comment: only in clause?

Comment: and in tidyverse there are dplyr?

Comment: Some R users just use base R. Most rely on packages to add functionality. To use a package you need two steps. 1) "Install the package" to download the code to your computer. Only need to do this once. 2) "load" the package into your current session using `library(PACKAGE_NAME_HERE)` to make those functions available to you.  `dplyr` is a popular package for data manipulation. `tidyverse` is a collection of related packages that includes `dplyr`. More info here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/  and https://www.tidyverse.org/

Comment: @JonSpring Ah thanks, wasn't aware of that.  Deleted

Comment: and anything with only basic packgae for solve this problem ?

Comment: @dado `ave()` is base `R`; something like `B$y <- ave(B$x, B$x, FUN=seq_along)`